# サイトへ設置している広告のiframeタグにクラス名を付与したい

Tags: javascript

・サイトへ設置している広告のiframeタグにクラス名を付与したいです
・どう書けば良いでしょうか？
・iframeが表示されるのを待つ必要はある？

・iframe.className = "hoge"？
・addClassNameは非標準？

Comment: iframeの中の要素に対してクラス名をつけるということですか?
それとも、<iframe> tag に対してなのでしょうか?

Comment: 「サイトへ設置している広告の」とありますが、 `<script src=".../adsbygoogle.js">` といったタグから動的に生成される iframe にクラスを付与したいということですか？

Comment: js等から「外部を経由して動的に生成される iframe タグ自体」にクラスを付与したい、です

Answer (score 2):

生の DOM API を使うなら、 `getElementById()` 等でDOM要素を取得し、 [`element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Element/className) でスペース区切りのクラス名を置き換えます。最近のブラウザであれば [`element.classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/element/classList) で簡単に追加することもできるようです。

ご指摘の [`addClassName()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/addClassName/) は prototype.js のメソッドかと思います。

> iframeが表示されるのを待つ必要はある？

DOM要素に対して操作を行いますから、対象のDOM要素が生成されている必要があります。

広告を埋め込むタグより後ろに書くだけで済むかもしれませんが、それでダメなら何らかの方法で iframe の生成ないし読み込みを待つ必要があります。[iframe の load イベントはバブリングが行われない](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6953610/2818869)ようですから、Mutation Observer を使ったり、タイマーで監視したり、といった形になるかと思います。